# Including REST-generated RSS feed

Tags: java, spring, rest

I've some problems to understand the functionality of RSS in my special situation.
I've a REST service (written in Java using Spring) which reads some information from a database and dynamically generates the RSS page. The pubdate element of each item is filled by the current date.
The service is reachable under an URL like "http://intern.system.com/rest/api/rss".
I took that URL and include it into a wiki page (the wiki is in this scenario the RSS reader).

The background of this workflow is the following: The database is filld with events or todo's for the next few days. Each event has a title, a description and a date. Until now this information is picked up by hand and transferred to show on a wiki page.
My goal is to automate this process. I want to generate a RSS feed of the events or todo's for the current day (that makes my REST service) and automatically show it on a wiki page.

Is this a good way to do? Does the RSS is shown the whole day (or only by the first call) and for all visitors? F.e. one person enters the page at 8 o'clock, another at 9. Both should see the same information for the day. I think the REST service is called twice in that case. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not problem but as we are developers, we should chase best practices on what we are building. So your case reminds me caching your rest service. If your data is daily updated, you can use caching property which is mostly preferred for static resources. You can add `@Cacheable("rssCache")` annotation to your **component** methods, after the first call, the result will be cached.

Comment: Thanks for the good idea. The workflow is ok so far: The method creates the feed and I've only add the @cachable annotation?

Comment: There is a good documentation here, you can check it out : [spring-cache](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial)

Comment: I've one more question: As I understand, the method is called once and the result is stored in the cache. Next time, the information is loaded from the cache and the method is skipped. But how can I realize that the feed is built every morning with the events for the current day?

Comment: Well, if you have a chance to use other cache libraries like ehcache, you can configure your cache timeout it' config xml(ehcache.xml) - because there is no time setting property in spring, you have to give it from outside. And spring encourages you to set expire time directly through cache provider : [spring cache 36.8](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-specific-config)